# C3.js unable to visualize

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, c3

I have a code that looks like this and I tried to run it but it doesn't give me any output. Is it because of my Chrome's javascript console?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Load c3.css -->
<link href="c3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Load d3.js and c3.js -->
<script src="d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="c3.min.js"></script>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>title </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#chart',
data: {
  columns: [
    ['data1', 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
    ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
  ]
}
});
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have c3.css, d3.v3.min.js and c3.min.js in the same directory that you have this HTML file.

Having Chrome's javascript console open will not affect d3 or c3.